# How to fix "** (Mix) The task "compile.all" could not be found" when I run `mix test`

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Recently started using exercism to learn elixir and I'm running into issues using mix. I'm completely new to using this tool so I've probably missed something basic.

When I run `mix test` in a directory with a tests subdirectory I get an error.

> ** (Mix) The task "compile.all" could not be found

When I run `mix deps.get` or `mix deps.compile` I get another error

> ** (Mix) The task "archive.check" could not be found

What am I doing wrong here? I imagine I need to install some task somehow?

I'm expecting to run some unit tests with a pass/fail condition but an error I documented above is thrown instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I did wrong. I forgot to install all the dependencies.

You can find a list of the full installation process [at the elixir web page](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like)